# multiple cross-ratios and extensions of the Moebius group

Tags: projective-geometry

I have a very naive question, I am wondering whether there exist an extension of the Moebius group for permutations of the 4 points in a cross ratio to the case of multiple cross ratios?

If I take n points on the projective line, I can build n-3 independent cross ratios. How do they transform under permutations of the labels? In the case n=4 the permutations give the action of the Moebius group, with the cross ratio \rho transforming to 1/\rho, \rho-1, etc. depending on the permutation. For n>4 mixed transformations appear, with things like \rho_1 -> \rho_1/\rho_2 for n=5, and more and more complicated rational functions as n increases. Does anyone know if there is a group structure associated to this more general cases?

Thanks,
Simone

Answer (score 1):

In the case of $n$ points on the extended complex plane, the "multiply cross-ratio" is actually a point of an orbifold of dimension $n-3$. The existence of a nontrivial group structure depends on the relative positions of these points (i.e. whether the "multiply cross-ratio" is a singularity of the orbifold).

It is throughly discussed using only elementary methods in my article: https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.07583